# jQuery как проверить нет ли в массиве элемента с определенным значением val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Есть несколько чекбоксов:

```
 <div id="checkboxes-1">
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='32'/>Первый</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='33'/>Второй</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='34'/>Третий</label>
 </div>
```

Как можно задать условие, ЕСЛИ в массиве среди отмеченных чебкосов `$('#checkboxes-1').find('input:checked')` нет `input` с `val() === '32'`, ТО...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input.checkbox:checked")).map(e => +e.value);
let arrayHasValue = (arr, search) => arr.includes(search);
let search = 32;

if (arrayHasValue(values, search))
    console.log('есть');
else
    console.log('нет');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes-1">
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='32' class="checkbox" checked/>Первый</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='33' class="checkbox" checked/>Второй</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='34' class="checkbox"/>Третий</label>
 </div>
```

---

Более краткий вариант:

```js
let has =  document.querySelector('input.checkbox[value="32"]:checked');

if (has)
    console.log('есть');
else
    console.log('нет');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes-1">
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='32' class="checkbox" checked/>Первый</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='33' class="checkbox" checked/>Второй</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='34' class="checkbox"/>Третий</label>
 </div>
```

---

C *Jquery*

```js
let has = $('input.checkbox[value=32]:checked').length > 0


if (has)
    console.log('есть');
else
    console.log('нет');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes-1">
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='32' class="checkbox" checked/>Первый</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='33' class="checkbox" checked/>Второй</label>
     <label><input type="checkbox" value='34' class="checkbox"/>Третий</label>
 </div>
```

Comment: больше макарон jquery c натив js, больше!

Comment: @teran а где было jquery с натив?  вот только сейчас вторым вариантом добавил. а первый без jquery был. так что ваш комментарий неуместен

Comment: В краткий вариант и добавить `has=(v)=> ...value="${v}"...`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не было, зато у автора будет, когда к себе скопирует

Comment: @teran если выделить в функцию - то ничего катастрафического не произойдёт. Я надеюсь у людей есть мозг, чтобы применить это как следует

Comment: Спасибо большое, ответ помог!